# Chrome extension connect-src

Tags: google-chrome-extension, fetch, content-security-policy

I'm trying to build a Chrome extension and I need to load/save some data from/to the https://address.com. My manifest.json is as below:

```
"permissions": [
    "geolocation",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "https://address.com/"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';connect-src 'self'  https://address.com/;"
```

But I'm running into the below issue when I'm trying to load, I'm not sure what is the issue and how to fix it.

> Refused to connect to 'https://address.com/graphql' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' blob: .....

Please suggest, thanks.

Fetch Code:

```
try {
      fetch("https://address.com/graphql", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ query: "{ getList(page:1, limit: 10) { t } }" })
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => console.log("getList: ", res.data));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("getListError:", error);
    }
```

**I just noticed another thing, the code works fine on sites like stackoverflow.com but giving error on facebook, twitter ... any idea.**

Comment: Show the code/HTML that connects to `https://address.com/graphql`.

Comment: Updated the fetch code.

Comment: Remove the last `/` in CSP so it becomes `https://address.com`

Comment: you mean in manifest file at content_security_policy?? If so, I did ... no luck.

Comment: Don't forget to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page after editing manifest.json. BTW you don't need content_security_policy at all.

Comment: of course, I'm reloading and yes I tried removing the content_security_policy - still no luck ... do you think I've to add any response headers on the server?

Comment: Is this in a content script? In that case you're seeing CSP error from the web page. Do the request in your background script and use messaging to transfer results to the content script.

Comment: ok, let me try that.. and update you. Thanks.

Comment: can you think of any reasons ... why the same code is working on stackoverflow and not on twitter or facebook?

Comment: Like I said, it would happen if you do the request in a content script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201790/discussion-between-surya-chandra-rao-gandreddi-and-woxxom).

Comment: You connect-src directive is "connect-src 'self'  https://address.com/;" while the error message you state shows ""connect-src 'self' blob: .....". Where does the "blob:" come from? Could it be that you have more than one CSP defined? Check both response headers and meta tag. You will need to pass every CSP present.